# Optimize Numba and Numpy function

Tags: python, optimization, numba

I'm trying to make this piece of code to run faster, but I can't find any more tricks that could speed this up.

I get a runtime of about 3 microseconds, the issue is that I'm calling this function a couple of million times and the process just ends up taking to long. I have the same implementation in Java (with just basic for loops) and basically, the computations are instantaneous for even large training data (This is for an ANN)

Is there a way to speed this up?

I'm running Python 2.7, numba  0.43.1 and numpy  1.16.3 on Windows 10

```
x = True
expected = 0.5
eligibility = np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1])
positive_weight = np.array([0.2,0.2,0.2])
total_sq_grad_positive = np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1])
learning_rate = 1

@nb.njit(fastmath= True, cache = True)
def update_weight_from_post_post_jit(x, expected,eligibility,positive_weight,total_sq_grad_positive,learning_rate):
        if x:
            g = np.multiply(eligibility,(1-expected))
        else:
            g = np.negative(np.multiply(eligibility,expected))
        gg = np.multiply(g,g)
        total_sq_grad_positive = np.add(total_sq_grad_positive,gg)
        #total_sq_grad_positive = np.where(divide_by_zero,total_sq_grad_positive, tsgp_temp)

        temp = np.multiply(learning_rate, g)
        temp2 = np.sqrt(total_sq_grad_positive)
        #temp2 = np.where(temp2 == 0,1,temp2 )
        temp2[temp2 == 0] = 1
        temp = np.divide(temp,temp2)
        positive_weight = np.add(positive_weight, temp)
        return [positive_weight, total_sq_grad_positive]
```

Comment: "I have the same implementation in Java (with just basic for loops) " Do quite the same thing with your Python code. Every vectorized operation translates to a for loop with a uneccessary temporary array. Since Numba (Python->LLVM-IR->LLVM-Backend) is quite similar to Clang(C->LLVM-IR->LLVM-Backend), write your code C-like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: It seems that @max9111 is right. Unnecessary temporary arrays is where the overhead comes from.

For the current semantics of your function, there seems to be two temporary arrays that cannot be avoided --- the return values `[positive_weight, total_sq_grad_positive]`. However, it struck me that you may be planning to use this function to update those two input arrays. If so, by doing everything in-place we get the most speedup. Like this:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

x = True
expected = 0.5
eligibility = np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1])
positive_weight = np.array([0.2,0.2,0.2])
total_sq_grad_positive = np.array([0.1,0.1,0.1])
learning_rate = 1

@nb.njit(fastmath= True, cache = True)
def update_weight_from_post_post_jit(x, expected,eligibility,positive_weight,total_sq_grad_positive,learning_rate):
    for i in range(eligibility.shape[0]):
        if x:
            g = eligibility[i] * (1-expected)
        else:
            g = -(eligibility[i] * expected)
        gg = g * g
        total_sq_grad_positive[i] = total_sq_grad_positive[i] + gg

        temp = learning_rate * g
        temp2 = np.sqrt(total_sq_grad_positive[i])
        if temp2 == 0: temp2 = 1
        temp = temp / temp2
        positive_weight[i] = positive_weight[i] + temp

@nb.jit
def test(n, *args):
    for i in range(n): update_weight_from_post_post_jit(*args)
```

If updating the input arrays is not what you want, you can begin the function with

```
positive_weight = positive_weight.copy()
total_sq_grad_positive = total_sq_grad_positive.copy()
```

and return them as in your original code. This is not nearly as fast, but still faster.

---

<s>I am not sure whether it can be optimized to be "instantaneous"; I am a little surprised that Java could do it since this looks like a pretty complicated function to me, with time-consuming operations like `sqrt`.</s>

But, did you use `nb.jit` on the function(s) calling this function? Like this:

```
@nb.jit
def test(n):
    for i in range(n): update_weight_from_post_post_jit(x, expected,eligibility,positive_weight,total_sq_grad_positive,learning_rate)
```

On my computer, this cuts the running time in half, which makes sense since Python function calls have a really high overhead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. Indeed I do call the function from another jit function, however, I#m using classes here and I do the trick where I basically extract this method from the class, so there is some extent to how much I can do this since I can#t do this from the class. Maybe there is a better way of circumventing that?

Comment: Just a small comment on compilerflags. Quite often, but not in this case (only 3 divisions) the division by zero checking reduces performance while not beeing necessary. You can deactivate this with error_model="numpy".

Comment: I implemented said changes and I could definitely see a speed up, thanks! Improving upon this, is there some way to skip the middle and of calling a function outside the class and having the jit class return the temporary matrices? Basically updating the "self" variables, but outside of a class? Thanks!

Comment: Omg I just refreshed my knowledge on python pass by reference, as long as the arguments are an object (for example a numpy array) they are always passed by reference!